# could not build or repl plutus-pioneer-program

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program

I'm trying to build the plutus-pioneer program, and I assume that having the environment working is important also in order to build real smart-contracts;

I've set up nix and cache and I'm also sure to be working with the correct commit; I'm trying to build from inside the nix-shell launcehd from the plutus directory (which is assumed to resolve dependecies) but still I get the following error:

```
cabal build --minimize-conflict-set

Warning: Requested index-state 2021-10-20T00:00:00Z is newer than
'hackage.haskell.org'! Falling back to older state (2021-10-19T23:39:06Z).
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: lobemo-scribe-systemd-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: libsystemd-journal (dependency of lobemo-scribe-systemd)
[__1] rejecting: libsystemd-journal-1.4.5, libsystemd-journal-1.4.4,
libsystemd-journal-1.4.3, libsystemd-journal-1.4.2, libsystemd-journal-1.4.1,
libsystemd-journal-1.4.0, libsystemd-journal-1.3.4, libsystemd-journal-1.3.3,
libsystemd-journal-1.3.1, libsystemd-journal-1.3.0 (conflict: pkg-config
package libsystemd>=209, not found in the pkg-config database)
[__1] trying: libsystemd-journal-1.2.0
[__2] next goal: base (dependency of lobemo-scribe-systemd)
[__2] rejecting: base-4.14.1.0/installed-4.14.1.0 (conflict:
libsystemd-journal => base>=4.6 && <4.8)
[__2] skipping: base-4.15.0.0, base-4.14.3.0, base-4.14.2.0, base-4.14.1.0,
base-4.14.0.0, base-4.13.0.0, base-4.12.0.0, base-4.11.1.0, base-4.11.0.0,
base-4.10.1.0, base-4.10.0.0, base-4.9.1.0, base-4.9.0.0, base-4.8.2.0,
base-4.8.1.0, base-4.8.0.0 (has the same characteristics that caused the
previous version to fail: excluded by constraint '>=4.6 && <4.8' from
'libsystemd-journal')
[__2] rejecting: base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1, base-4.7.0.0, base-4.6.0.1,
base-4.6.0.0, base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0, base-4.4.1.0, base-4.4.0.0,
base-4.3.1.0, base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2, base-4.2.0.1, base-4.2.0.0,
base-4.1.0.0, base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2, base-3.0.3.1 (constraint from
non-upgradeable package requires installed instance)
[__2] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, libsystemd-journal,
lobemo-scribe-systemd)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, libsystemd-journal,
lobemo-scribe-systemd
```

could anyone please explain to me what am I doing wrong?

#### additional infos

evrything executed in nix-shell environment

##### ghc version

```
ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.10.4.20210212
```

##### cabal varsion

```
cabal --version
cabal-install version 3.6.2.0
compiled using version 3.6.2.0 of the Cabal library
```

Comment: Did you do "cabal update" before "cabal build" ?

Comment: I could only build inside a nix shell. Install nix and then instead of your command type nix-shell. It should build the thing and open the shell. From within that, you can then execute your cabal-commands.

Comment: @kindofdev yes I did ```cabal update```, I retryied justy in case and the error persists;

Comment: @Jey I'm already in a nix-shell environment

Comment: Ok. Did you execute "nix-shell" from within the folder of plutus-apps ?

Comment: Did you do `cabal build` on ppp/code/week0x folder ?

Comment: @Jey no I launched ```nix-shell``` form the ```plutus``` repository, I'm trying from ```plutus-apps``` now

Comment: @kindofdev yes I tryied ```cabal build``` on ```plutus```, ```plutus-apps``` and the ```week0x``` folders (with aprropriate tags setted before launching the ```nix-shell``` from the ```plutus``` repo

Comment: You need to launch nix-shell from plutus-apps, not plutus

Comment: @Jey @kindofdev launching ```nix-shell``` from ```plutus-apps``` solved the issue; if any of you want to answer the question I'll mark it as soilved, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run `nix-shell` from within the plutus-apps folder and then (inside this nix shell) navigate to the plutus-pioneer folder to run the cabal command.